# How to resolve NXDOMAIN in centos using bind/named package

Tags: linux, centos, bind

I am trying to configure DNS server on centos 7. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GGE29AsxS0&list=PLQMGSIjEVIgGuFU6ssmenX1KwYg0dsLMk&index=12&ab_channel=SridCloud) link.
when I run `dig -x 192.168.40.107` I don't receive any answers record. here is output

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.13 <<>> -x 192.168.40.107
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 24981
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;107.40.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.   86400   IN  SOA 168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA. . 0 28800 7200 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 09 16:18:26 +04 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you
My config files are

/etc/named.conf

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.40.107; };
#   listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
    secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
    allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.40.0/24; };
    recursion yes;
    forwarders {
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;
  };
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
  channel default_debug {
    file "data/named.run";
    severity dynamic;
  };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
include "/etc/named/named.conf.local";
```

/etc/named/named.conf.local

```
zone "okd.local" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/named/zones/db.okd.local"; # zone file path
};

zone "40.168.192.in-addr.erpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/named/zones/db.40.168.192"; # 192.168.40.0/24 subnet
};
```

/etc/named/zones/db.okd.local

```
$TTL      604800
@     IN     SOA     okd4-services.okd.local. admin.okd.local. (
               1     ; Serial
          604800     ; Refresh
           86400     ; Retry
         2419200     ; Expiry
          604800     ; Nagitave cache TTL
)

; name servers - NS Records
    IN      NS      okd4-services

; name servers - A Records
okd4-services.okd.local.        IN     A     192.168.40.107

; OpenShift container plateform cluster - A Records
okd4-bootstrap.lab.okd.local.   IN      A     192.168.40.103
okd4-master1.lab.okd.local.     IN      A     192.168.40.104
okd4-worker1.lab.okd.local.     IN      A     192.168.40.105
okd4-worker2.lab.okd.local.     IN      A     192.168.40.106


; OpenShift internal cluster IPs - A Records

api.lab.okd.local.                              IN      A     192.168.40.107
api-int.lab.okd.local.                          IN      A     192.168.40.107
*.apps.lab.okd.local.                           IN      A     192.168.40.107
etcd-0.lab.okd.local.                           IN      A     192.168.40.104
console-openshift-console.apps.lab.okd.local.   IN      A     192.168.40.107
oauth-openshift.apps.lab.okd.local.             IN      A     192.168.40.107

; OpenShift internal cluster IPs - SRV Records

_etcd-server-ssl._tcp.lab.okd.local     86400   IN     SRV    0     10    2380    etcd-0.lab
```

/etc/named/zones/db.40.168.192

```
$TTL 604800
@     IN     SOA     okd4-services.okd.local. admin.okd.local. (
               6     ; Serial
          604800     ; Refresh
           86400     ; Retry
         2419200     ; Expiry
          604800     ; Nagitave cache TTL
)

; name servers - NS Records
    IN      NS      okd4-services.okd.local.

; name servers - PTR Records
107        IN     PTR     okd4-services.okd.local.

; OpenShift container Plateform Cluster - PTR Records

103    IN    PTR    okd4-bootstrap.lab.okd.local.
104    IN    PTR    okd4-master1.lab.okd.local.  
105    IN    PTR    okd4-worker1.lab.okd.local.  
106    IN    PTR    okd4-worker2.lab.okd.local.  
107    IN    PTR    api.lab.okd.local.           
107    IN    PTR    api-int.lab.okd.local.
```

Comment: I think your problem is `erpa`?

Comment: How can I fix this ? I am new in this and don’t know that much about it.

Comment: Change the `erpa` typo to `arpa`?

Comment: Thank you. I also had an other error which was file path of zone file.